# Obtain payload of post

Tags: node.js, jquery

I've used jQuery to ajax post some data to a nodejs webserver.

The webserver code receives the post but I don't know how to retrieve the payload, and the nodejs documentation web is just awful. I've tried dumping the request object to the debugger console but I can't see the data there. How do I access the payload of a post?

The documentation says the request object is an instance of `http.IncomingMessage` and exposes a `data` event with the signature `function (chunk) { }` where chunk is either a string or a `Buffer`, but if you don't know where or how you're supposed to hook up to this event, or how to use a Buffer then this isn't terribly helpful.

---

I notice that there is a second, more narrative manual hidden under "community" rather than the "docs" link. This is good. It is currently not available. This is not so good.

---

I have been asked whether I'm using a framework or trying to do it "native". Ignorance prevents me from answering directly, so instead here is the code

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('sys');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');
var URL = require('url');

var mimeMap = { htm : "text/html", css : "text/css", json : "application/json" };

var editTemplate = fs.readFileSync("edit.htm").toString();

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  request.addListener('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('got a chunk');
  });

  var body, token, value, mimeType;
  var path = URL.parse(request.url).pathname;

  console.log(request.method + " " + path);

  switch (path) {
    case "/getsettings":
      try {
        mimeType = "application/json";
        body = fs.readFileSync("/dummy.json");
      } catch(exception) {
        console.log(exception.text);
        body = exception;
      }
      //console.log(body.toString());
      break;  
    case "/setsettings":
      console.log(request); //dump to debug console
      //PROCESS POST HERE
      body = ""; //empty response
      break;  
    case "/": 
      path = "/default.htm";
      mimeType = "text/html";
    default:
      try { 
        mimeType = mimeMap[path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)];
        if (mimeType) {
         body = fs.readFileSync(path);
        } else {
          mimeType = "text/html";
          body = "<h1>Error</h1><body>Could not resolve mime type from file extension</body>";
        }
      } catch (exception) {
        mimeType = "text/html";
        body = "<h1>404 - not found</h1>";
      }
      break;
  }
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeType});
  response.writeHead(200, {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'});
  response.writeHead(200, {'Pragma': 'no-cache'});
  response.end(body);  
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

---

Now I have added this

```
request.addListener('data', function(chunk){
  console.log('got a chunk');
});
```

to the start of the success function for createServer. It seems to work like this, which I suppose means the success function is called prior to the listeners. If this is *not* the correct place to bind then someone please tell me.

Comment: are you using some kind of web framework like express or are you trying to do it in a 'native' way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over at "//PROCESS POST HERE" add a `req.pipe(process.stdout);` it will output the post data to the console.

You can also pipe it to a file `req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(MYFILE))` or even back out to the browser `req.pipe(res);`

See an example here: http://runnable.com/nodejs/UTlPMl-f2W1TAABS

You can also add your own handlers to the events, data, error and end

```
var body = '';

request.addListener('data', function(chunk){
  console.log('got a chunk');
  body += chunk;
});

request.addListener('error', function(error){
  console.error('got a error', error);
  next(err);
});

request.addListener('end', function(chunk){
  console.log('ended');
  if (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  }
  console.log('full body', body);
  res.end('I have your data, thanks');
});
```

Oh and as to the 'native or module' question, you could use a module like express which will parse the body for you, and populate req.body with the result (skipping the addListener pain and even parsing formdata or json for you). See http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. As you can see in my own sample code I have just discovered the binding of handlers such as you suggest, and although my data fits nicely in one chunk I'm still grateful for the explanation of how to accumulate chunks. Could you clarify *where* these events are supposed to be declared? Am I doing it in the right spot?

Comment: You have the right spot marked a "//PROCESS POST HERE" though you might want to also check that `req.method === 'POST'`, again a library such as express would make that easier with `app.post('/setSettings', function (req, res, next) { console.log('body already parsed', req.body); next(); });`